# Ошибка перебора двумерного массива объектов класса c++

Tags: c++, указатели, память, локальные-переменные

имеется класс **Chess**, который содержит свойство **field** - двумерный массив объектов класса **Cell**. **Cell**, в свою очередь, содержит свойство **figure** - объект абстрактного класса **Figure**. Проблема появляется, когда я пытаюсь перебрать двумерный массив **field**. Текст ошибки: *Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0000000000000000 в Chess.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x0000000000000000*. Ошибка возникает только при обращении к методу **GetName** объекта **Pawn**, который содержится в **Cell** в **field[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LPzq.png)**, но до этого, когда в цикле вызывается этот же метод внутри **field[0][0]**, никакой ошибки нет, и в консоль выводится нужная мне информация.

Соответственно, если сделать массив размером [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LPzq.png), то ошибки тоже нет, но при увеличении размера внутреннего массива хотя бы на 1, ошибка сразу возникает.

При этом, если в режиме отладки посмотреть на значения **field[1][0]** и **field[1][0]**, то они, как будто бы, ссылаются на одни и тот же объект, но я не понимаю, как такое может происходить.

Скриншот и код прикрепил. Ошибка возникает на строке 81.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я допускаю ошибку :(

```
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;


enum class Color { white, black };
map <Color, string> stringColor = {
        {Color::white, "White"},
        {Color::black, "Black"}
};

class Figure
{
public:
    Figure(Color figureColor)
    {
        this->color = figureColor;
    }

    Color GetColor(void) const
    {
        return color;
    }

    virtual string GetName(void) = 0;

protected:
    Color color;

};


class Pawn :public Figure {
public:
    Pawn(Color pawnColor) :Figure(pawnColor) 
    {
    };

    string GetName(void) override {
        return "Pawn";
    };
};

class Cell
{
private:
    Color color;
    Figure* figure;

public:
    Cell()
    {
        color = Color::white;
        figure = NULL;
    }
    Cell(Color cellColor)
    {
        color = cellColor;
        figure = NULL;
    }

    void SetFigure(Figure* newFigure) {
        this->figure = newFigure;
    }

    Figure* GetFigure(void) {
        return figure;
    }

    string ToString()
    {
        if (figure == NULL)
        {
            return stringColor[color];
        }
        else
        {
            string figureColor = stringColor[figure->GetColor()];
            string name = figure->GetName();
            string result = name + "[" + figureColor + "]";
            return result;
        }
    }
};

class Chess
{
private:
    Cell field[1][2];

    void CreateField(void)
    {
        bool isWhite = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                field[i][j] = Cell(isWhite ? Color::white : Color::black);
                isWhite = !isWhite;
            }
            isWhite = !isWhite;
        };
    }

    void SetStartingLineUp(void)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                Color color = i == 1 ? Color::black : Color::white;
                Pawn pawn(color);
                field[i][j].SetFigure(&pawn);
            }
        };

    }
public:
    Chess(void)
    {
        CreateField();
        SetStartingLineUp();

    }

    void ShowField(void)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                cout << setw(10) << field[i][j].ToString();
            }
            cout << endl;
        };
    }
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    Chess chess;
    chess.ShowField();

    int a;
    cin >> a;
}
```

[image: Значение переменных в режиме отладке на строке 134]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Pawn pawn(color);
field[i][j].SetFigure(&pawn);

....

void SetFigure(Figure* newFigure) {
    this->figure = newFigure;
}
```

Т.е. передаем и сохраняем адрес локального объекта, который немедленно после этого вызова умирает...

Хотя бы

```
field[i][j].SetFigure(new Pawn(color));
```

или иным способом, не хранящим указатель на локальный объект, т.е. по сути висящую ссылку.

Само собой, в новом варианте надо озаботиться корректным освобождением памяти...

Comment: Ты гений! Спасибо большое!!